# De Rham isomorphism for relative and compactly supported cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I am currently reading up on cohomology with compact supports, and am looking for a reference as to whether the De Rham isomorphism $H_\textrm{DR}^*(M)\simeq H^*(M;\mathbb R)$ exists for the compactly supported cohomologies $H_\textrm{DR,c}^*(M)$ and $H_c^*(M;\mathbb R)$ as well. I think it probably does, because I suspect two more things to be true as well:

- that $H_\textrm{DR,c}^*(M)$ is the direct limit of relative cohomology groups $H_\textrm{DR}^*(M,M\setminus K)$ in the same way that $H_c^*(M;\mathbb R)$ is the direct limit of $H^*(M,M\setminus K;\mathbb R)$,
- and that the De Rham isomorphism $H_\textrm{DR}^*(M)\simeq H^*(M;\mathbb R)$ exists for the relative cohomology groups $H_\textrm{DR}^*(M,M\setminus K)$ and $H^*(M,M\setminus K;\mathbb R)$ too.

I have however not been able to find a source for that at all, neither for the De Rham isomorphism on compactly supported cohomology nor for the two weaker statements that together would imply it. The only thing I was able to find is [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/146302/503660) answer on MathOverflow, which refers to a similar-looking theorem in a book on sheaf theory that I don't really understand. Can anyone maybe point me to a more elementary proof, or outline one here?

Comment: It is true for sheaves because, for a Hausdorff second countable smooth manifold $X$, the De Rham complex $\Omega^{\bullet}$ of sheaves is a *soft* resolution for $\underline{\Bbb R}$ and $X$ is $\sigma$-compact so that means it is both a $\Gamma,\Gamma_C$-acyclic resolution, hence $H^\bullet(X,\Bbb R)\cong H^\bullet_{DR}(X)$ and $H^\bullet_C(X,\Bbb R)\cong H^\bullet_{DR,C}(X)$

Comment: What definition of $H^*(M; \mathbb{R})$ and $H^*_c(M; \mathbb{R})$ are you using? Singular cohomology? It would be good to know exactly which proof of the de Rham isomorphism you want to generalize. The isomorphism for relative cohomology follows from the LES if you have a natural isomorphism.

Comment: @ronno I was referring to singular cohomology, yes. The proof I know gives an explicit isomorphism by integrating over simplices; it seems very much plausible that the same thing works for compactly supported homology, but checking that all the details of the proof carry over seems like a lot of effort to go through, so I was hoping there was some way around that. Applying the 5-lemma to the LES seems like a good alternative at least for relative homology indeed, though it still requires having a natural homomorphism in the first place of course.

Comment: If your map is given by integrating on (smooth) simplices then of course it is natural over open inclusions. I think for the statements you want it will be easiest to go through sheaf cohomology but I don't have a reference for all the pieces.